# A question about past tense and present tense

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, present-simple

I talked about my travel experience in Japan with my friend. He asked me : How many time have you been to Japan?I have been there only once.

So I should say

1. It was my first time to be there

   or
2. It is my first time to be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should say

> "It was my first time there".

'Was' refers to an event that happened in the past. Since you had visited Japan sometime in the past, past tense should be used.

Also note that "to be" is incorrect.

Bonus: The correct question is

> "How many times have you been to Japan?"

Note the plurality in the question above.

Comment: Thank you CinCout, your explanation is very understandable, it dose solve my question

Comment: @ChengShihMing If the answer is helpful, you may upvote and/or mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi , CinCout, I am new here, I don't really how how to upvote , you meant choosing the up triangle sign on the left?and how can I mark it as accepted? I tried but not sure is it worked..

Comment: Yes, the up triangle is for the up vote, the down one for the down vote. And yes, the tick mark is for accepting the answer (as you rightly did).

Comment: Hi CinCout , I chose the upvote , but it is still "0" , it should be "1" ,right ? I don't know why it didn't work , sorry ... But I appreciate your answer for sure.

Comment: @ChengShihMing You can vote up only if you have at least 15 reputation points. Refer this http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: Oh, then I got it , I don't have enough points so far , thank you for explaining it ☺